# VBA Access - Opening Outlook to get current user name causes error

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I had been using the below code for a month or so, but it has started to throw an error. It's called from an access module to get the current user's full name. Now when it runs it give error 287 (application-defined or object-defined error)

```
Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ses = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
strFullName = ses.CurrentUser.Name  **stops at this line**
Set app = Nothing
Set ses = Nothing
strFirst = Mid(strFullName, InStr(1, strFullName, ",") + 1)
strLast = Left(strFullName, InStr(1, strFullName, ",") - 1)
fncGetIDName = strFirst & " " & strLast
```

I've figured out that the code only errors if I don't already have Outlook open. (which is why I thought it worked originally) After going into debug, adding a watch to 'app' or 'ses' then hitting run causes it to work, and continue to work untill the db is restarted. I assume this has something to do with outlook not fully opening or initializing or something. I tried to search other issues like this but couldn't find any similiar problems, any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add ses.Logon before retrieving the user name.

Comment: This worked, Used info found @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220124(v=office.11).aspx to get rid of the popup dialog. Thanks! Will accept when I can.